# Firefox won't render past script tag on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, firefox

When my application is deployed on Heroku, Firefox is unable to render the page past a particular script tag. However, a locally deployed version of the same application works just fine. Here's a link to the Heroku-based site which (as of writing) is experiencing this issue:

https://idom-docs.herokuapp.com

You'll note that there are no especially interesting errors in the console. The page simply stops rendering once it encounters the script tag.

---

Below is a GIF demonstrating the issue. On the left is a Chromium-based browser, and on the right is Firefox. Note how the Chromium browser is able to scroll through the full set of examples, but in Firefox, even though all the resources have been fetched, only the first example is rendered, and after that the page hangs with a loading indicator. When switching to a locally deployed version of the website though, Firefox has no issues rendering the page.

[image]

Here's a brief sample of what the script looks like:

```
<script async type="module">
    import {{ mountWidgetExample }} from "/_static/custom.js";
    mountWidgetExample("some-element-id", "some-uuid", "/_host");
</script>
```

`custom.js` contains the following:

```
import { mountLayoutWithWebSocket } from "idom-client-react";

const LOC = window.location;
const HTTP_PROTO = LOC.protocol;
const WS_PROTO = HTTP_PROTO === "https:" ? "wss:" : "ws:";
const IDOM_MODULES_PATH = "/_modules";

export function mountWidgetExample(mountID, viewID, idomServerHost) {
  const idom_url = "//" + (idomServerHost || LOC.host);
  const http_idom_url = HTTP_PROTO + idom_url;
  const ws_idom_url = WS_PROTO + idom_url;

  const mountEl = document.getElementById(mountID);
  const enableWidgetButton = document.createElement("button");
  enableWidgetButton.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Enable Widget"));
  enableWidgetButton.setAttribute("class", "enable-widget-button");

  enableWidgetButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
    fadeOutElementThenCallback(enableWidgetButton, () => {
      {
        mountEl.removeChild(enableWidgetButton);
        mountEl.setAttribute("class", "interactive widget-container");
        mountLayoutWithWebSocket(
          mountEl,
          ws_idom_url + `/_idom/stream?view_id=${viewID}`,
          (source, sourceType) =>
            loadImportSource(http_idom_url, source, sourceType)
        );
      }
    })
  );

  function fadeOutElementThenCallback(element, callback) {
    {
      var op = 1; // initial opacity
      var timer = setInterval(function () {
        {
          if (op < 0.001) {
            {
              clearInterval(timer);
              element.style.display = "none";
              callback();
            }
          }
          element.style.opacity = op;
          element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + op * 100 + ")";
          op -= op * 0.5;
        }
      }, 50);
    }
  }

  mountEl.appendChild(enableWidgetButton);
}

function loadImportSource(baseUrl, source, sourceType) {
  if (sourceType == "NAME") {
    return import(baseUrl + IDOM_MODULES_PATH + "/" + source);
  } else {
    return import(source);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I marked the script as `async` (which is similar to `defer`) when there wasn't an `src`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer